# Uncaught Error in snapshot listener: FirebaseError after logging out in React Native App

Tags: reactjs, firebase, react-native, google-cloud-firestore

This is my first time making a `react native application` and everything works as it should. But when I try to log out I get errors.

`Uncaught Error in snapshot listener: FirebaseError: Missing or insufficient permissions`.

I have 3 requests. This error for all three requests, also the application `does not handle when user = null`, that is, in those places where I want to `render user.email` I get an `error on undefined`, although in my idea these pages should not have loaded after the log out.

The problem in the firebase rules cannot be, I want the request not to be made at all when there is no user

I want the Welcome page to load after logout and no requests, and user = null. After logging in everything works as I expect, the main problem is in the logout. I think the problem  in fetching or useEffect.

I've tried different options but can't find what the problem is. If you need any more pieces of code or clarifications, I'll edit the question.

```
AppBody 

//request example is similar to others
  const fetchedEmails = async () => {
    if (user && !noUser) {
      try {
        const ref = collection(db, "emails");
        const q = query(ref, where("user", "==", user.uid));
        const unsubscribe = onSnapshot(
          q,
          { includeMetadataChanges: true },
          (querySnapshot) => {
            const arr = [];
            querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
              arr.push({
                ...doc.data(),
                id: doc.id,
              });
            });
            dispatch(setEmails(arr));
          }
        );
        return () => {
          unsubscribe();
        };
      } catch (err) {
        //console.log(err);
      }
    }
    if (!user || noUser) {
      dispatch(setEmails([]));
      return;
    }
  };
   useEffect(() => {
      fetchedEmails();
      fetchedSubs();
      fetchedUserData();
      // eslint-disable-next-line
    }, []); 
    
    useEffect(() => {
      fetchedEmails();
      fetchedSubs();
      fetchedUserData();
    // eslint-disable-next-line
  }, [user]);
```

**Navigation**

When there is no user, the Welcome page should load, and when there is a user, then the AppName page

```
 <Stack.Navigator
      screenOptions={{
        headerStyle: {
          backgroundColor: headerBgColor(),
        },
        headerTintColor: headerColor(),
      }}
    >
      {user ? (
        <Stack.Group>
          <Stack.Screen
            name="AppName"
            component={Navigation}
            options={{
              headerShown: false,
            }}
          />
          <Stack.Screen name="AddSub" component={AddSubScreen} />
          <Stack.Screen name="AddEmail" component={AddEmailScreen} />
          <Stack.Screen name="ManageEmail" component={ManageEmails} />
          <Stack.Screen name="AccountSettings" component={AccountScreen} />
        </Stack.Group>
      ) : (
        <Stack.Group>
          <Stack.Screen name="Welcome!" component={BaseScreen} />
          <Stack.Screen name="Login" component={LoginScreen} />
          <Stack.Screen name="Registration" component={RegScreen} />
        </Stack.Group>
      )}
    </Stack.Navigator>
```

**AccountSettings**

```
  const { logout } = UserAuth();

  const handleLogout = async () => {
    try {
      await logout();
      dispatch(setUser(null));
      dispatch(setNoUser(true));
      navigator.navigate("Welcome!");
    } catch (error) {
      // console.log(error.message);
    }
  };

<AccountItem style={{ justifyContent: "center", alignItems: "center" }}>
        <AButton
          style={{ width: 200, marginTop: 30 }}
          onPress={() => handleLogout()}
        >
          <SpanText>Log out</SpanText>
        </AButton>
      </AccountItem>
```

**UserAuth**

```
  const logout = () => {
      return signOut(auth);
  };
```